# Выравнивание структуры IMAGE_DOS_HEADER

Tags: windows, pe

Структура `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {...}` состоит из 18 `WORD` параметров и одного `LONG`. Получается, ее размер: `18 * sizeof(WORD) + sizeof(LONG) = 40` байт. Однако, `sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)` дает нам 64 байта, это же подтверждает и документация. Читал, что данная структура выравнивается на границу 8 байт, и, видимо, с этим и связан ее размер в 64 байта.

Собственно, *вопрос*: как происходит это выравнивание ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определение структуры `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {      // DOS .EXE header
    WORD   e_magic;                     // Magic number
    WORD   e_cblp;                      // Bytes on last page of file
    WORD   e_cp;                        // Pages in file
    WORD   e_crlc;                      // Relocations
    WORD   e_cparhdr;                   // Size of header in paragraphs
    WORD   e_minalloc;                  // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_maxalloc;                  // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_ss;                        // Initial (relative) SS value
    WORD   e_sp;                        // Initial SP value
    WORD   e_csum;                      // Checksum
    WORD   e_ip;                        // Initial IP value
    WORD   e_cs;                        // Initial (relative) CS value
    WORD   e_lfarlc;                    // File address of relocation table
    WORD   e_ovno;                      // Overlay number
    WORD   e_res[4];                    // Reserved words
    WORD   e_oemid;                     // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    WORD   e_oeminfo;                   // OEM information; e_oemid specific
    WORD   e_res2[10];                  // Reserved words
    LONG   e_lfanew;                    // File address of new exe header
  } IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;
```

Обратите внимание, что поля `e_res` и `e_res2` - это массивы из 4 и 10 элементов соответственно. Отсюда получается, что размер структуры равен `(14+4+2+10)*sizeof(WORD) + sizeof(LONG) = 64`.

Выравнивание в данном случае не применяется.

Comment: Да, действительно, по собственной невнимательности этот момент я упустил. Спасибо Вам!